# How to create a mask layer in CocosSharp rectangle?

Tags: c#, cocoa-touch, xamarin, cocos2d-iphone, cocossharp

Is it possible to create a mask layer in Cocoa/CocosSharp?? 
I was looking [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/cocossharp/ccdrawnode/), but couldn't find it. I also googled for this with no luck.

What I want to do, is to create rectangle with a lot of holes.

Something like this:
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/placing-an-image-inside-another-with-photoshop-cs6/

Thanks for help